# Oracle PL/SQL Parameter value from parameter name in String

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, procedure

Hi I need to retrieve a parameter value where the parameter name is in different parameter.

Lets say the proc is as below

```
PROCEDURE findValue
(
    p_date             IN VARCHAR2,
    p_name             IN VARCHAR2,
    p_class             IN VARCHAR2,
    p_paramname             IN VARCHAR2,
)
IS
```

Now lets say i want to pass `p_paramname` as `p_date` and further use the value of `p_date` parameter in PL/SQL block, how do i use it ?

Comment: What is the business problem that you are trying to solve?  Obviously, you could have an `IF` block that looks at different values of `p_paramname` and executes different bits of code depending on the value.  I'm guessing, however, that isn't what you're asking...

Comment: Hi Justin, I am trying to make a wrapper procedure that can call different types of functions having each different number of parameters. They way i am thinking is to get the order of parameters (`p_name,p_class`) to be passed in lets say `p_paramname` and further use the values in the function call.

Comment: What is the relationship among the various procedures that your wrapper procedure would be calling?  If you're trying to build something very dynamic, you're probably approaching the problem incorrectly.  But if the procedures that the wrapper procedure would be calling are all very similar in nature, their signatures should be similar as well.

Comment: The signature of various procedure being called is different and i cannot change it now for backward compatibility. The various functions being called are independent and i want to use this wrapper to be able to call any of them dynamically so i can use it with other application.

Comment: How many possible parameter sets are you trying to support?  You could get into dynamic PL/SQL but that will generally produce pretty complicated code that is pretty difficult to support, maintain, and debug.

Comment: I am trying to support 5 parameters whose order and number would come in one parameter, and am open to dynamic sql as well, but still not able to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can afford PL/SQL table inputs then try the logic below:

```
CREATE TYPE param_tbl_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
    (p_param_names param_tbl_type,
     p_param_values param_tbl_type)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    l_dyn_func_str VARCHAR2(4000);
    l_ret_val VARCHAR2(4000);
    vCursor integer;
    fdbk PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN

   -- make sure you have equal number of params and currespondin values. 
   -- Index much match too. i.e. if p_param_names(0) is 'p_currency' then p_param_value(0) must be 'USD' (value of currency)
   IF p_param_names.COUNT <> p_param_values.COUNT THEN
      raise_application_error(-2000,'Incorrect number of arguments');
   END IF;

   -- use this variable to generate anonymous block code
   l_dyn_fun_str:='BEGIN :retval :=  function_tobe_called (';

   -- loop through each parameter and add to the parameter list 
   FOR i in 1..p_param_names.COUNT LOOP
      IF i=0 THEN
        l_dyn_fun_str:=l_dyn_fun_str||':'||l_param_name(i);
      ELSE
        l_dyn_fun_str:=l_dyn_fun_str||','||':'||l_param_name(i);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   l_dyn_fun_str:=l_dyn_fun_str||'); END;'

   -- open cursor and associate with function call string (l_dyn_fun_str)
   vCursor:=DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
   DBMS_SQL.PARSE(vCursor,l_dyn_fun_str);

   -- loop through parameter values and associate them with bind variables
   DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(vCursor,':retval',l_ret_val);
   FOR j in 1..p_param_values.COUNT LOOP
      DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(vCursor, ':'||l_param_names(j), l_param_values(j));
   END LOOP;
   -- execute function 
   fdbk := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE (vCursor);

   -- get output of function 
   DBMS_SQL.VARIABLE_VALUE (vCursor, 'retval', l_ret_val);
   RETURN l_ret_val;


END;
```

Note: The code syntax may not be perfect but the pseudo should still work for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Brainhash, If you look at my comment above for what i am trying to accomplish , this solution could get very big and difficult to implement .

Comment: @user3842265 how exactly the above will be difficult? can you provide more examples/sample code with expected output.

Comment: Edited my answer. Please review.  You may need some minor tweaks but hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out to plan for how i could handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the value of P_PARAMNAME against the possible parameter names and branch accordingly.  E.g.,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE matt_test1 (p_date        IN VARCHAR2,
                                        p_name        IN VARCHAR2,
                                        p_class       IN VARCHAR2,
                                        p_paramname   IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  CASE p_paramname
    WHEN 'P_NAME' THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Did something with P_NAME.  Value was ' || p_name);
    WHEN 'P_DATE' THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Did something with P_DATE.  Value was ' || p_date);
    WHEN 'P_CLASS' THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Did something with P_CLASS.  Value was ' || p_class);
    ELSE
      raise_application_error (-20001, 'Invalid parameter name: ' || p_paramname);
  END CASE;
END matt_test1;


begin
  matt_test1(SYSDATE,'Fred','English 101', 'P_DATE');
  matt_test1(SYSDATE,'Fred','English 101', 'P_NAME');
  matt_test1(SYSDATE,'Fred','English 101', 'P_CLASS');
end;
```

Output:

```
Did something with P_DATE.  Value was 11-Aug-2015
Did something with P_NAME.  Value was Fred
Did something with P_CLASS.  Value was English 101
```